# Проблема в реализации поиска анаграммы в словаре

Tags: c#, winforms

не знаю как реализовать поиск анаграмм из файла (словаря). 
Например мне нужно найти анаграммы в словаре, в WinForms есть textBox для ввода слова, и кнопка "Найти" для поиска анаграммы в словаре, нужно чтобы при нажатие на кнопку начался поиск в словаре, и выводился результат на экран(richTextBox). 
*Вот пример формы, уже с некоторой функциональностью, сохранение, печать на принтер, изменения пользовательских настроек.* 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Берете слова из словаря, сортируете в словах буквы по алфавиту - получаете новые (сортированные) слова. Ищете в новых словах дубликаты - они и будут указывать на анаграммы.

Answer (score 0):

1. Отсортируйте буквы в ведённом слове в алфавитном порядке
2. Отсортируйте таким же образом буквы слов в вашем словаре
3. Ищите прямые совпадения между преобразованным таким образом введённым словом и преобразованными словами из словаря. Что найдётся - то и анаграмма.
4. Проверьте, нет ли совпадения у найденных сочетаний слов ещё до их преобразования - может это не анаграмма, а точно такое же слово нашлось в словаре, как и введённое.